# HttpCore: Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: java, apache, http, apache-httpclient-4.x, serversocket

I copied the code from the Basic HTTP GET example at the [Apache HttpCore site.](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/examples.html)

When I run it (after installing all the appropriate JARs correctly), I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at ElementalHttpGet.main(ElementalHttpGet.java:83)
```

I cannot figure out, or find, a solution.

This is the source code:

```
/*
 * ====================================================================
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 * ====================================================================
 *
 * This software consists of voluntary contributions made by many
 * individuals on behalf of the Apache Software Foundation.  For more
 * information on the Apache Software Foundation, please see
 * <http://www.apache.org/>.
 *
 */



import java.net.Socket;

import org.apache.http.ConnectionReuseStrategy;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection;
import org.apache.http.impl.DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpRequest;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpCoreContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpProcessor;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpProcessorBuilder;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestConnControl;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestContent;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestExpectContinue;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestTargetHost;
import org.apache.http.protocol.RequestUserAgent;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

/**
 * Elemental example for executing multiple GET requests sequentially.
 */
public class ElementalHttpGet {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpProcessor httpproc = HttpProcessorBuilder.create()
            // Required protocol interceptors
            .add(new RequestContent())
            .add(new RequestTargetHost())
            // Recommended protocol interceptors
            .add(new RequestConnControl())
            .add(new RequestUserAgent("Test/1.1"))
            // Optional protocol interceptors
            .add(new RequestExpectContinue(true)).build();

        HttpRequestExecutor httpexecutor = new HttpRequestExecutor();

        HttpCoreContext coreContext = HttpCoreContext.create();
        HttpHost host = new HttpHost("localhost", 8080);
        coreContext.setTargetHost(host);

        DefaultBHttpClientConnection conn = new DefaultBHttpClientConnection(8 * 1024);
        ConnectionReuseStrategy connStrategy = DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy.INSTANCE;

        try {

            String[] targets = {
                    "/",
                    "/servlets-examples/servlet/RequestInfoExample",
                    "/somewhere%20in%20pampa"};

            for (int i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
                if (!conn.isOpen()) {
                    Socket socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(), host.getPort());
                    conn.bind(socket);
                }
                BasicHttpRequest request = new BasicHttpRequest("GET", targets[i]);
                System.out.println(">> Request URI: " + request.getRequestLine().getUri());

                httpexecutor.preProcess(request, httpproc, coreContext);
                HttpResponse response = httpexecutor.execute(request, conn, coreContext);
                httpexecutor.postProcess(response, httpproc, coreContext);

                System.out.println("<< Response: " + response.getStatusLine());
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
                System.out.println("==============");
                if (!connStrategy.keepAlive(response, coreContext)) {
                    conn.close();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Connection kept alive...");
                }
            }
        } finally {
            conn.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Silly question but are you sure there is something actually running on the 8080 port ?

Comment: .... actually I'm not. How do I check?

Comment: Omg... Browser -> http://localhost:8080 ?

Comment: Did you launch a tomcat or something similar for your tests ?

Comment: No I haven't launched Tomcat. What is supposed to be running there? I was under the impression that this code runs when I type the address in my browser.

Comment: @vzamanillo What am I supposed to see?